# How do I use and open the file_path from tkinter in pandas.read_csv to have it then be plotted with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, filepath

I am plotting right now a spectrum of a metal probe (for spectral analysis). The data of the spectrum that has to be plotted is given through a .txt file. I used panda to format that .txt file, so i can use it to plot the spectrum.

It works when I enter the file, or file_path (as a string), manually but now i wanted to be more sophisticated and have a potential user choose a file him or herself.

**My problem is:**

I think, that tkinter somehow breaks the plotting itself or it never even gets to the plotting part in the code. When i enter the file manually and comment tkinter out, the plot works wonderfully, yet when i try and use tkinter, the plot never shows, even when i put in the file_path or name manually and comment tkinter out.

`file_name = fd.askopenfilename()`
does indeed return a string (checked by `print(type(file_name)`, so theoretically it fits the required format for later putting it in `data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\s+',etc`

yet this version doesn't work, only if i enter the file path, or name in strings manually.

**My question is:**

How can I make a potential user choose a file, insert that file name or path in the `pd.read_csv()` (which renders the file readable for being plotted after), and then having it be plotted successfully? I'm very new to programming and i feel i am a bit out of my depth here. Any help and hints are very appreciated!

I do print the data set before as i want to see if panda rendered the file properly. Here would be a sample data set (I saved it as sample.txt)

```
*sample.txt*

Ag-3080 09.08.2021 08:43:40

161,673 0,00000000
162,713 0,00467774
162,718 0,00482345
162,724 0,00486770
162,729 0,00470309
162,735 0,00452067
162,741 0,00439058
162,746 0,00456918
```

Here is my full code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

root = tkinter.Tk()  # pointing root to Tk() to use it as Tk() in program
root.withdraw()  # hides small tkinter window
file_name = fd.askopenfilename()  # Returns opened path as str

# General

probe = 'Ag-3080  09.08.2021  08:43:40'
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\s+', names=['Wavelength', 'Intensity'], skiprows=1, decimal=',')

print(data)

# Plot

X = data.Wavelength
Y = data.Intensity

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X, Y, color='C4')
plt.title(probe)
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')

# Interval

ax.set_xticks([min(data.Wavelength), (max(data.Wavelength))])
ax.set_yticks([min(data.Intensity), (max(data.Intensity))])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` sets the GUI backend to the default value, which I believe is `Qt`. Maybe try adding `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` before that line to force matplotlib to use `Tk` as the backend.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @jfaccioni I tried it, but it still does not work :/ When i run the code, the window to choose file does pop up, i can open and print the file, yet it never plots. So i think it must have something to do with the pandas line in combination with tkinter. When i comment tkinter out and put the file path (or name) manually it all works.

Comment: @8349697 this code doesn't throw an error (unfortunately). I debugged it and it prints the file and even takes the data from the file and sets the y- and x-axis yet it never plots the spectrum. I wonder if tkinter and matplotlib have some kind of backend contradiction going on. Is there another way to choose a file and have matplotlib use it?

Comment: @katzeMelli if you don't mind the learning curve, you could try to move on to `Qt` (through the third-party `PyQt` package) as the GUI framework instead of `Tk`. I've successfully embedded matplotlib figures into the GUI using it.

Comment: @jfaccioni embrace the learning curve! Thank you so much, i'll try and see if i can get a result with it!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I created a csv file with arbitrary data for the Wavelength and Intensity names. Tkinter gets the file path, pandas reads the csv file, matplotlib shows the plot.

Comment: You can also view this tutorial if you want to embed the plot in a GUI: [Embedding Matplotlib in graphical user interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#embedding-matplotlib-in-graphical-user-interfaces).

Comment: @8349697 thank you for the link, also I'm surprised to read that it works for you! Which program are you running the code with? I'm using PyCharm CE, maybe that's where the problem lies?

Comment: @8349697 - i followed the link and used the instructions on matplotlib! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!